# .htaccess - Redirect not working as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, hashtag, mediatemple

I can't get this to work on my site:

```
# BEGIN pushState Routing
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 

RewriteRule ^/tournament/(0-9)+$ /#tournament/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
# END pushState Routing
```

When I do `...example.com/tournament/11` I get a 404. It should redirect to `example.com/#tournament/11` so that `Backbone.js` enables pushState and removes the hashtag itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
# BEGIN pushState Routing
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80 
RewriteRule ^/?(tournament/\d+)/?$ /#$1 [R=301,NE,L,NC]
# END pushState Routing
```

Leading slash is not matched in `.htaccess` so better to make it optional to make it compatible with .htaccess and Apache config.

Comment: That did it! What's the first `?` for before `(tour...)`?

Comment: As I wrote in answer, that just makes leading slash optional in regex pattern.

Comment: Got it, It had a time limit before I could accept it.